# What does scope mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I asked my friend who moved recently to Texas: "How's living there? A lot of Tacos, huh?"

She replied back: "Lol. Pretty much. Leaves scope for the imagination".

I know what scope means in dictionary, like "scope of work", but in this context I couldn't get it.

Comment: How did your friend explain it?

Comment: @Lawrence Since English is not my first language, I honestly stopped asking her about words meaning because she always use slang words, that will make the conversation boring. I find most of them on google but I couldn't find this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *scope* should be understood in this way:

> **scope** *noun*
>   2 The opportunity or possibility to do or deal with something.
>   ‘the scope for major change is always limited by political realities’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scope)

She may have taken "a lot of tacos" to imply "not a lot of variety", replying humorously that the situation leaves her plenty of opportunity to use her imagination.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I *think* she's meaning that it's a place that allows her to use her imagination a lot.

This is not a common English phrase. As an American, I had no idea what it was supposed to mean when I first read it. When doing a little research, it looks like most of the hits are for a single book, so this is probably an expression that only a few people use.